# iphone Application Crash

Tags: iphone

My application works fine on all my devices. But it crashes on clients devices.
Below is the crash log.

Can anyone help..

I am lost...

```
Incident Identifier: 8C60587C-4152-4E29-A1F1-AC780B63BB45
CrashReporter Key:   09cad4f13a4c6b81b63d81504cd8b58e5eea4fd7
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         cadoinpiedi [73]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/4074DCAE-E48F-443A-9215-1498C2940984/cadoinpiedi.app/cadoinpiedi
Identifier:      cadoinpiedi
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-03-10 10:10:16.637 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3 (8F190)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315fca1c 0x315eb000 + 72220
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b193b4 0x36ae6000 + 209844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b11bf8 0x36ae6000 + 179192
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x34df0a64 0x34dac000 + 281188
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36f8406c 0x36f7e000 + 24684
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x34deee36 0x34dac000 + 273974
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x34deee8a 0x34dac000 + 274058
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x34deef5a 0x34dac000 + 274266
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36f82c84 0x36f7e000 + 19588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x32d3f48a 0x32ca1000 + 648330
10  CoreFoundation                  0x32d3f4c4 0x32ca1000 + 648388
11  CoreFoundation                  0x32cb19d0 0x32ca1000 + 68048
12  cadoinpiedi                     0x0000bc7c 0x1000 + 44156
13  Foundation                      0x3299d388 0x32907000 + 615304
14  libxml2.2.dylib                 0x371f620e 0x371eb000 + 45582
15  libxml2.2.dylib                 0x371febba 0x371eb000 + 80826
16  Foundation                      0x3299cd5e 0x32907000 + 613726
17  cadoinpiedi                     0x0000b528 0x1000 + 42280
18  Foundation                      0x329192ee 0x32907000 + 74478
19  Foundation                      0x32919270 0x32907000 + 74352
20  CFNetwork                       0x3684040a 0x36831000 + 62474
21  CFNetwork                       0x36834f42 0x36831000 + 16194
22  CFNetwork                       0x36834e34 0x36831000 + 15924
23  CFNetwork                       0x36834de6 0x36831000 + 15846
24  CFNetwork                       0x36834d58 0x36831000 + 15704
25  CFNetwork                       0x36834cd6 0x36831000 + 15574
26  CoreFoundation                  0x32d16a72 0x32ca1000 + 481906
27  CoreFoundation                  0x32d18758 0x32ca1000 + 489304
28  CoreFoundation                  0x32d194e4 0x32ca1000 + 492772
29  CoreFoundation                  0x32ca9ebc 0x32ca1000 + 36540
30  CoreFoundation                  0x32ca9dc4 0x32ca1000 + 36292
31  GraphicsServices                0x30f51418 0x30f4d000 + 17432
32  GraphicsServices                0x30f514c4 0x30f4d000 + 17604
33  UIKit                           0x35f1fd62 0x35ef1000 + 191842
34  UIKit                           0x35f1d800 0x35ef1000 + 182272
35  cadoinpiedi                     0x00002210 0x1000 + 4624
36  cadoinpiedi                     0x00002190 0x1000 + 4496

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315fd3ec 0x315eb000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b1a6d8 0x36ae6000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b1abbc 0x36ae6000 + 215996

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315fdfbc 0x315eb000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x328fa094 0x328f4000 + 24724
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x328fb04a 0x328f4000 + 28746
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x328fa60a 0x328f4000 + 26122
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b1a58a 0x36ae6000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b1abbc 0x36ae6000 + 215996

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315fd3ec 0x315eb000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b1a6d8 0x36ae6000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b1abbc 0x36ae6000 + 215996

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315fac00 0x315eb000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315fa758 0x315eb000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32d172b8 0x32ca1000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32d19562 0x32ca1000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32ca9ebc 0x32ca1000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32ca9dc4 0x32ca1000 + 36292
6   WebCore                         0x31a0037a 0x319fa000 + 25466
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b1930a 0x36ae6000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b1abb4 0x36ae6000 + 215988

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315fac00 0x315eb000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315fa758 0x315eb000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32d172b8 0x32ca1000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32d19562 0x32ca1000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32ca9ebc 0x32ca1000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32ca9dc4 0x32ca1000 + 36292
6   Foundation                      0x329317f6 0x32907000 + 174070
7   Foundation                      0x32924382 0x32907000 + 119682
8   Foundation                      0x329965c6 0x32907000 + 587206
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b1930a 0x36ae6000 + 209674
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b1abb4 0x36ae6000 + 215988

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315fcc60 0x315eb000 + 72800
1   CoreFoundation                  0x32d1c8f2 0x32ca1000 + 506098
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b1930a 0x36ae6000 + 209674
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b1abb4 0x36ae6000 + 215988

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3fcca48c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x0019bc6c      r7: 0x2fdfe658
    r8: 0x3f60dbf8    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x361eafd8     r11: 0x361e82f0
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfe64c      lr: 0x36b193bb      pc: 0x315fca1c
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x19fff +cadoinpiedi armv7  <d248922f1069f2847106e98c1e5a11ba> /var/mobile/Applications/4074DCAE-E48F-443A-9215-1498C2940984/cadoinpiedi.app/cadoinpiedi
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <8dbdf7bab30e355b81e7b2e333d5459b> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30e94000 - 0x30e98fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <2e841b3daf303b38bbd82e0954659af4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x30f1e000 - 0x30f4cfff  MIME armv7  <a9fa461fb9e7378789a3091b69504a09> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x30f4d000 - 0x30f59fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <c37066a0784335d189f009ff4965717d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x30f5a000 - 0x30f5cfff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3106e000 - 0x3106efff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x31157000 - 0x3115ffff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <d0167be199b234f5bd233380111b2735> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x31160000 - 0x3117ffff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x31256000 - 0x31259fff  ActorKit armv7  <f7aa6cdd654231988aafcf448978f450> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x3125a000 - 0x31263fff  ITSync armv7  <dc57c003aad83864827ccf95fc579563> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x31268000 - 0x312aafff  CoreAudio armv7  <d45e275525ef3c32b36e0f1020cad705> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x312ab000 - 0x312aefff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x312c9000 - 0x312d3fff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x31304000 - 0x31337fff  StoreServices armv7  <a74659288dea34bca7a7911c19cf2c28> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x31338000 - 0x31339fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3143a000 - 0x3143bfff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x31543000 - 0x31547fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <2c61a8f7e7bf32d890e957d768d769ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x31548000 - 0x3157bfff  QuickLook armv7  <29d2d981d1d6358381f5716ee37314b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x3157c000 - 0x3157ffff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <0479a171c00d3f629d639713acb72b5b> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x315b0000 - 0x315d0fff  AppleAccount armv7  <4e0ac5cf93b338ab8c5f34ba3c5e2ee4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x315eb000 - 0x31602fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <29eb602b615b3c3b95722868100a2d1c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x31658000 - 0x3165dfff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x3168a000 - 0x316bdfff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x316ee000 - 0x3173ffff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x31784000 - 0x31790fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c78c28a259ad35ddb01512beb5fcea95> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x31795000 - 0x31832fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <e354aeb3d96e30338e90cc3638ffe81b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x3183d000 - 0x31844fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x31845000 - 0x31999fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <3b599e96ffe93b1ea2aa6026dee809dc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3199a000 - 0x3199ffff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <a19b1caf96c73568b14a1660f147ae2f> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x319a0000 - 0x319f9fff  EventKit armv7  <0d4e597ee229337183e96e921a72e30a> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x319fa000 - 0x32002fff  WebCore armv7  <9c7e4a156f6a381ea02f99ece48a46fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x32005000 - 0x32007fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <4d521bd4a1be3448a7d2bac1d09c5ff9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x32008000 - 0x32017fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <f258d39dc7d93faa9c9ff5cf81c5dcbd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x32020000 - 0x32021fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x320de000 - 0x320e3fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3220b000 - 0x32214fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <5b634ed28af339719e3c279224531ccb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x32216000 - 0x3224afff  VideoToolbox armv7  <aec2e22a2055380e82d4d0279faad0a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x32267000 - 0x3227cfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x322b2000 - 0x323d3fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <54e27b8aa66c32b48ffeadadcc514331> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x323d4000 - 0x3241afff  CoreTelephony armv7  <2b9ebb05fdea38938dde802c8280b3ea> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32426000 - 0x32428fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x32450000 - 0x32450fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <68322643de8030978c862de530055bd9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x325cb000 - 0x325dafff  Notes armv7  <d9c976ca976e3d029f69febd48f17601> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x325dd000 - 0x325e8fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x325eb000 - 0x3262efff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <ffab9d7f5b5b315085783caf030932bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x3262f000 - 0x326d5fff  Celestial armv7  <1d37083fe4253a2fb271c0ca0a42e283> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x326dd000 - 0x326e0fff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x32758000 - 0x32765fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x32766000 - 0x327adfff  MessageUI armv7  <35a81f5d4eb03467a1447db80337e570> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x327be000 - 0x328c6fff  CoreData armv7  <9843a401dd1d322383e3e40021cc8b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x328ee000 - 0x328f3fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <1eaf25ddd98e3a249bca536671c5819d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x328f4000 - 0x32901fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <6c4eeb08757b365f8429ef6747f89ad3> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x32907000 - 0x32a26fff  Foundation armv7  <60d1a3b3937c3c7ab21d701fb337346c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x32a36000 - 0x32a36fff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x32a6b000 - 0x32a6cfff  DataMigration armv7  <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x32c22000 - 0x32c42fff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x32c71000 - 0x32ca0fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x32ca1000 - 0x32d86fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <4f643539f91f330790f112ea7150b3a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x32fab000 - 0x33040fff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33046000 - 0x33049fff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x33137000 - 0x3313dfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <c9798b4dd29335248000d698dea938bd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x34bf1000 - 0x34c60fff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x34d02000 - 0x34d39fff  Security armv7  <163414ba17df347ca76088015010e2c4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x34d56000 - 0x34d92fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <79d00adb09de3da991ed21f48f27adb4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x34d9b000 - 0x34d9bfff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x34dac000 - 0x34df6fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x34e23000 - 0x34e27fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <36e96d0a7dda330281a43172d0ada49a> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x34e2d000 - 0x34e3dfff  WebBookmarks armv7  <6956561235333e74b8ff316cb2edc93e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x3532c000 - 0x35446fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3549e000 - 0x354f3fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x35667000 - 0x3569ffff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x356b9000 - 0x357bdfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <f63386018d703534b766514e4bbbd1d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x357be000 - 0x357cefff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <66d9047da79a31daa887e6d84c42ecb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x357cf000 - 0x357d1fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <de8392b1117135e592a16e1cb6d26af5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x35a0e000 - 0x35a41fff  iCalendar armv7  <e52c54abaab734e8b0278f358217c4b5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x35a42000 - 0x35a5ffff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x35a60000 - 0x35aaefff  GMM armv7  <03cb1e098c4932e58b0933dfc58f9116> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x35ab8000 - 0x35d9ffff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <652c97e211553d4e84968a61f62a0ac5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x35da1000 - 0x35da2fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x35dba000 - 0x35dbafff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x35dbb000 - 0x35e02fff  CoreLocation armv7  <565c18af7dfc3c92a63cc4c249913650> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x35e65000 - 0x35e7bfff  EAP8021X armv7  <b755ecad7b6a3009a5f4a0fdc5f9bdd7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x35e80000 - 0x35ea9fff  ContentIndex armv7  <f5a3613ec5b6392995d7ed0742f7419f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x35ebb000 - 0x35ef0fff  AddressBook armv7  <64500984cfb13a098c3c687c37a80fff> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x35ef1000 - 0x3627efff  UIKit armv7  <bc8d14fa59e136b6a28ac025384daf08> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x362d1000 - 0x3630efff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x36310000 - 0x36315fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x36316000 - 0x3631ffff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x36320000 - 0x36327fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x36328000 - 0x36356fff  DataAccess armv7  <3a2e67aa1d8834b7a8fc2fbb56654b15> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x3671f000 - 0x36726fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3672e000 - 0x3673cfff  OpenGLES armv7  <f02d1c50f0f33991adb1a2caed02eb77> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x36741000 - 0x36780fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <b5735b0f3dba32c087c5b58aa48ae592> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x36781000 - 0x36830fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x36831000 - 0x368f0fff  CFNetwork armv7  <84a2d312145e3dbf97aea052927dcdb9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3691c000 - 0x36945fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x36946000 - 0x3695ffff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x36a37000 - 0x36a95fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d3f7360687333cad987890c314ae0d6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x36aad000 - 0x36aaefff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <5f077c4d204d3cd7b04452c42d41f763> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x36ae6000 - 0x36b67fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <caa1846ad2583d1b84c1a15c50c126a2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x36c62000 - 0x36d4ffff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x36d55000 - 0x36d58fff  CertUI armv7  <9060fe03a4943ef295531feced9a17dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x36e81000 - 0x36e83fff  MailServices armv7  <adbbafb0ea513e00ae3c6ec8f0251410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x36e84000 - 0x36ebcfff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x36ebd000 - 0x36f47fff  Message armv7  <e2a583f640503bdba0eac23e7a919f84> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x36f7e000 - 0x37042fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <f855251d90a53bdbb5d5a39fdbde6d9b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x37048000 - 0x37088fff  CoreMedia armv7  <66ee3ed5265f3d49a274dc9a07d27d52> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3709a000 - 0x370bafff  MobileSync armv7  <4df400c4559435889eccd88db77a110c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x3711a000 - 0x3711cfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x37139000 - 0x371eafff  WebKit armv7  <8f2fd63295d83121b1db9097938ad31f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x371eb000 - 0x37294fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x37295000 - 0x3729bfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3731d000 - 0x37469fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <46c1dd5571de3f7dae97dcde85ca933c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x3759b000 - 0x375aefff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x375af000 - 0x375fcfff  CoreMotion armv7  <e0349aa7dd1c3454a970ea1939279801> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x37614000 - 0x37626fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <6d30b5ef735f36a79cfc82c9b6606db9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
```

Comment: You can symbolicate the crashlog with the DSYM file Xcode generated along with the app. Then you see exactly where the crash is. Just add the crashlog into the Xcode organizer.

Comment: This crash log is not symbolicated. It's impossible to tell where's the error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened the debug window in Xcode when running/crashing the app on the device?  Should show you the stacktrace there and allow you to investigate a bit easier.

Comment: Thats probably hard to do on/with a clients device.

Comment: Duh, OK, reread the question.  Counsel retracts the answer.  Guess I needed more coffee....

Comment: Problem is on client's device. I can't debug it.